# how to choose backup strategy?

Tags: sql-server, backup, database, sql, database-backup

I am DBA of a big online retail company. I am responsible for the
availability of the company’s database. The size of this database is 28GB,
and it handles an average of 120 transactions every minute. my main
concern is to **minimize the time required to restore the database** in case of a
failure. 
Describe the backup strategy that you will use.

Comment: "describe the backup strategy that you will use." You mean you're the DBA or we're the DBA? The wording sounds kind of like it's from a third-party than yourself.

Comment: Well for a start you don't think about just "backup strategy" to support a database that large and heavily used, you need to bake in resiliency from day one of the design. Rather than trying to make the time to backup one database as small as possible, you perhaps might start by deciding how long it can be offline for in a disaster and work backwards from that.

Comment: Homework question?

Comment: Sounds like homework to me. If the OP were actually the DBA of a big online retail comany he would probably already know the answer.

Comment: I'd really hope so, that said I'd love to know the site...could try buying something with user 'sa' ;)

Comment: @Chopper3, buying something with user `";drop *;` might be more interesting.

Answer (score 4):

My strategy would include:

- Implementing a Active-Passive Cluster
- Bare Metal Recovery Backups
- A warm-site spare if downtime costs justified it

Comment: Seems like you'd also want to just backup the DB. So you could do a DB level restore as well as file level restore, if you needed to.

Comment: @James, the answer was intentionally as vague/non-comprehensive as the question. But a good point none the less.

Comment: Bare Metal Recovery should imply backups - otherwise, you don't have anything to recover from. That said, it's a very good point that HA and DR *are not backups*.

Answer (score 2):

Consider [Microsoft System Center Data Protection Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/data-protection-manager/dpm-protect-sql.aspx) and maybe some training in this, or other, area.

Comment: What OS is the database running on...?